# Tensorflow - 'Unable to get element as bytes' error

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, neural-network, deep-learning

**The following code:**

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import pandas as pd



# DATA PREPARE
df = pd.read_csv('housing.csv')
df = df.dropna()
print(df.head)
print(df.describe())
print(df.info())



# NORMALIZATION
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler

scaler = MinMaxScaler()
scaler.fit(df[['housing_median_age', 'total_rooms', 'total_bedrooms', 'population', 'households', 'median_income',
               'median_house_value']])
df_scaled_cols = scaler.transform(df[['housing_median_age', 'total_rooms', 'total_bedrooms',
                                      'population', 'households', 'median_income', 'median_house_value']])
df_scaled_cols = pd.DataFrame(data=df_scaled_cols, columns=['housing_median_age', 'total_rooms', 'total_bedrooms',
                                                            'population', 'households', 'median_income',
                                                            'median_house_value'])

df = pd.concat([df_scaled_cols, df['ocean_proximity']], axis=1)



# DATAFRAME INTO X AND Y -> TRAIN TEST SPLIT
x_data = df[['housing_median_age', 'total_rooms', 'total_bedrooms', 'population', 'households', 'median_income',
             'ocean_proximity']]
y_label = df['median_house_value']

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x_data, y_label, test_size=0.3)



# FEATURE COLUMNS FROM DATA

m_age = tf.feature_column.numeric_column('housing_median_age')
rooms = tf.feature_column.numeric_column('total_rooms')
bedrooms = tf.feature_column.numeric_column('total_bedrooms')
population = tf.feature_column.numeric_column('population')
households = tf.feature_column.numeric_column('households')
income = tf.feature_column.numeric_column('median_income')
ocean = tf.feature_column.categorical_column_with_hash_bucket('ocean_proximity', hash_bucket_size=10)
embedded_ocean = tf.feature_column.embedding_column(ocean, dimension=4)

feat_cols = [m_age, rooms, bedrooms, population, households, income, embedded_ocean]



# 3 INPUT FUNCTIONS

train_input_func = tf.estimator.inputs.pandas_input_fn(x=X_train, y=y_train, batch_size=10, num_epochs=1000,
                                                       shuffle=True)
test_input_func = tf.estimator.inputs.pandas_input_fn(x=X_test, y=y_test, batch_size=10, num_epochs=1, shuffle=False)
predict_input_func = tf.estimator.inputs.pandas_input_fn(x=X_test, batch_size=10, num_epochs=1, shuffle=False)



# DNN_Reg MODEL

dnn_model = tf.estimator.DNNRegressor(hidden_units=[10,10,10], feature_columns=feat_cols)
dnn_model.train(input_fn=train_input_func, steps=1000)
```

**Causes the error:**

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py",
>   line 1278, in _do_call
>       return fn(*args)   File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py",
>   line 1263, in _run_fn
>       options, feed_dict, fetch_list, target_list, run_metadata)   File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py",
>   line 1350, in _call_tf_sessionrun
>       run_metadata) tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InternalError: Unable to get
>   element as bytes.
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:/Users/Admin/Documents/PycharmProjects/TF_Regression_Project/project.py",
>   line 69, in 
>       dnn_model.train(input_fn=train_input_func, steps=1000)   File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\estimator\estimator.py",
>   line 376, in train
>       loss = self._train_model(input_fn, hooks, saving_listeners)   File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\estimator\estimator.py",
>   line 1145, in _train_model
>       return self._train_model_default(input_fn, hooks, saving_listeners)   File
>   "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\estimator\estimator.py",
>   line 1173, in _train_model_default
>       saving_listeners)   File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\estimator\estimator.py",
>   line 1451, in _train_with_estimator_spec
>       _, loss = mon_sess.run([estimator_spec.train_op, estimator_spec.loss])   File
>   "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\monitored_session.py",
>   line 695, in **exit**
>       self._close_internal(exception_type)   File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\monitored_session.py",
>   line 732, in _close_internal
>       self._sess.close()   File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\monitored_session.py",
>   line 980, in close
>       self._sess.close()   File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\monitored_session.py",
>   line 1124, in close
>       ignore_live_threads=True)   File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\coordinator.py",
>   line 389, in join
>       six.reraise(*self._exc_info_to_raise)   File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\six.py",
>   line 692, in reraise
>       raise value.with_traceback(tb)   File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\estimator\inputs\queues\feeding_queue_runner.py",
>   line 94, in _run
>       sess.run(enqueue_op, feed_dict=feed_dict)   File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py",
>   line 877, in run
>       run_metadata_ptr)   File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py",
>   line 1100, in _run
>       feed_dict_tensor, options, run_metadata)   File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py",
>   line 1272, in _do_run
>       run_metadata)   File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py",
>   line 1291, in _do_call
>       raise type(e)(node_def, op, message) tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InternalError: Unable to get
>   element as bytes.

**What is wrong inside?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was the normalization.

Instead of sklearn method, I did the following:

```
df[['housing_median_age', 'total_rooms', 'total_bedrooms', 'population', 'households', 'median_income',
    'median_house_value']] = df[['housing_median_age', 'total_rooms', 'total_bedrooms', 'population', 'households', 'median_income',
               'median_house_value']].apply(lambda x: (x-x.min()) / (x.max()-x.min()))
```

So, to conclude, I do same thing as sklearn, but manually - with lambda.